# SAP GUI Error: ... cannot access class sun.awt.AppContext

Tags: java

After installing the SAP GUI:

```
java -jar PlatinGUI740_0-20012039.JAR install
```

(Which was flawless) I get the following error:

```
/opt/SAPClients/SAPGUI/bin/guistart conn=/H/172.20.3.13/S/3200
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sap.platin.base.splash.SplashWindow (in unnamed module @0x4f063c0a) cannot access class sun.awt.AppContext (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export sun.awt to unnamed module @0x4f063c0a
at com.sap.platin.base.splash.SplashWindow.getOwnerFrame(SplashWindow.java:99)
at com.sap.platin.base.splash.SplashWindow.splashImpl(SplashWindow.java:206)
at com.sap.platin.base.splash.SplashWindow.splash(SplashWindow.java:176)
at com.sap.platin.Gui.main(Gui.java:70)
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Change the Java version.**

In my case the default version was Oracle-Java-9 `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+140, mixed mode)`

I changed it to OpenJDK 8 `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)`

By using the command `sudo update-alternatives --config java`